# How to combine two list with different type?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have two list , one is list of ids
`List<int> ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3,4, 5};`

Another list with data
Person class has two properties Id and Name

```
List<Person> persons= new List<Person> { new Person { Name = "test1"},  new Person { Name = "test2"},  new Person { Name = "test3"}, new Person { Name = "test4"},  new Person { Name = "test5"}};
```

Now i want to populate the id for each persons from the list of ids.

Is there a way to do it in linq?

Comment: what is the basis for populating IDs to persons? what is the relation between those separate IDs and person names?

Comment: index, the both list will be of same length and the first list at end index will have the persons id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.. Assuming your lists are the same length

**for loop**

```
for (int i = 0; i < persons.Count; i++)
   persons[i].Id = ids[i];
```

**foreach Loop**

```
var index = 0;
foreach (var person in persons)
   person.Id = ids[index++];
```

**ForEach Extension method**

```
var index = 0;
persons.ForEach(person => person.Id = ids[index++]);
```

**Queue**

```
var queue = new Queue<int>(ids);
foreach (var person in persons)
   person.Id = queue.Dequeue();
```

---

**Note** *Linq* (Language Integrated Query) is for querying not for updating properties, so i don't recommend a *linq* approach at all. But who am i to judge...

**Enumerable.Range**  with side effects

```
Enumerable.Range(0, persons.Count).Select(i => persons[i].Id = ids[i]).ToList();
// or
var persons = Enumerable.Range(0, persons.Count).Select(i => { persons[i].Id = ids[i]; return persons[i]; }).ToList();
```

**Zip**  with side effects

```
ids.Zip(persons, (i, person) => person.Id = i).ToList();
// or
var persons = ids.Zip(persons, (i, person) => { person.Id = i; return person; }).ToList();
// or still very iffy
ids.Zip(persons, (i, person) => (i: i, person: person))
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(x => x.person.Id = x.i);
```

**Select**  with side effects

```
persons.Select((person, i) => person.Id = i).ToList();
// or
var persons = persons.Select((person, i) => { person.Id = i; return person; }).ToList();
```

<sub>*add many more here*</sub>

Comment: I wanted the person object with the ids populated as the result, zip and select approaches gives me list of int as an result

Answer (score 1):

`Select` overload with index as second argument and without side effects ;)

```
var personsWithId = persons
    .Select((person, id) => new Person
    {
        Id = id,
        Name = person.Name
    })
    .ToList();
```

If you have predefined list of ids and want to apply id to the person with same index from persons list

`Zip` without side effects ;)

```
var personIds = new[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
var personsWithId = persons
    .Zip(personIds, (person, id) => new Person
    {
        Id = id,
        Name = person.Name
    })
    .ToList();
```